# eclipse php project online problems

Tags: php, eclipse, error-handling, ftp

I ran into some problems when I tried to upload my php project to my server. I really can't figure what's wrong. The project is working when i run it on localhost, but when I copy the files to my server, something is wrong when I use "require". I simply require some php files in the same folder like this:

```
<?php
session_start ();
require 'guiParts.php';
require 'formfunctions.php';
...
```

And I get the following errors when I visit my website online:

> Warning: require(guiParts.php) [function.require]: failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   /www/zzl.org/m/v/l/mvlweb/htdocs/index.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required
>   'guiParts.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php') in
>   /www/zzl.org/m/v/l/mvlweb/htdocs/index.php on line 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in server configuration. Maybe its running php thru fcgi, maybe someting else...

try using full path

```
require __DIR__ . '/guiParts.php';
```

should work

Comment: it doesn't work for me :( I was wondering if it had something to do with eclipse. Because the error says Failed opening required 'guiParts.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php').. usr/lib/php is not a path that I made myself. I think it is some auto generated folders created by eclipse

Comment: I just tried making a simple php code using require. I made this with notepad and it worked when I put it online. Så then it must have something to do with the editor right?

Comment: Okay I found the problem.. and do I feel stupid. It should have been guiparts.php and not guiParts.php. Anyways, I'll accept your answer so the question is closed. thanks for your help